# Select difference between two tables sums also using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, difference

**Im trying to get the difference between two tables sums but i keep getting the wrong outcome **

```
Table1                                           Table2      

| product  | quantity |                          | product  | quantity |
| -------- | -------- |                          | -------- | -------- |
| a        | 7        |                          | a        | 2        |
| b        | 8        |                          | b        | 4        |
| c        | 9        |                          | c        | 1        |
| c        | 7        |                          | c        | 3        |
| a        | 3        |                          | a        | 2        |
| b        | 4        |                          | b        | 3        |
```

**I tried this queury but i got the wrong values:**

```
select table1.product, sum(table1.quantity) - sum(table2.quantity) as difference
from table1
  join table2 on table1.product = table2.product
group by table1.product,table2.product;
```

**Expected Outcome**

Table1

| product | difference |
| --- | --- |
| a | 6 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 12 |

Comment: @jarlh has answered so I am only going to comment. In SQL, the `FROM` clause (including `JOIN`) is executed before the `SELECT`. This means the query in your question gets 4 records for each product (each product has 2 records in `table1`, each of the 2 records is joined with 2 records in `table2`). You can verify that by doing a simple `SELECT *`

Comment: @Atmo, thank you for the explanation. As a general advice, it's safer to aggregate in subqueries before joining.

Comment: Also, a FULL OUTER JOIN would be required to include products only found in one of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION ALL` the tables (where you take `-quantity` for table2.) `GROUP BY` the result.

```
select product, sum(quantity)
from
(
  select product,  quantity from table1
  union all
  select product, -quantity from table2
) dt
group by product
```

**As requested - some comments:**

As a general advice, it's safer to `GROUP BY` (in subqueries) before joining - since a `JOIN` can result in multiple rows for a value.

Also, to include a product only found in one of the tables, an outer join would have been needed.

Comment: I would also add an explanation as to why the original query produced inflated numbers.

Comment: I did that in a comment below the question already.

Comment: @Atmo comments are not meant to stay around, answers are.